# Error with sending input at run time in a multithreaded client server socket program in python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, client-server

I've made this full duplex multi-threaded TCP server(python 3.6) which can listen and send messeges to multiple clients at a time(client send messages to this server taken at runtime from the client using input function of python 3). All goes well except when client sends a message other than 'hello' or 'goodbye' (I've predefined the responses to these two messages). When a client sends a random message like 'asdadsk' or 'asdasd' or anything other than hello or goodbye; this server is programmed to take input from console and send it to the client. so when i give it the input it just stop there. pressing ENTER does nothing. just nothing happens. nothing reachs the client. and due to this client also keeps waiting for a response.

Here is the interaction between a client and this server:

```
Connected to : 127.0.0.1 : 51811
<socket.socket fd=196, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 28985), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 51811)>
Client Sent: hello
Client Sent: hello
Client Sent: hello
Client Sent: asdasd
>>>>> :asdkkad
asdjajd

asdasda

ad
a
sda
sd
```

## multi-threaded server.py

```
    import socket
    import _thread


    def threaded_client(sock):

      sock.send(str.encode("Yokoso O-genki-desuka:)"))

      while True:
        data = sock.recv(4096).decode()

        # print(data)
        if data.lower() == 'hello':
            reply = 'Server Output: Dono yō ni watashi wa anata o tasukeru kamo shirenai- How may i help you? :D'
            print('Client Sent: ' + data.lower())
            sock.send(reply.encode())

        elif data.lower() == 'goodbye':
            reply = 'Server Output: Sayōnara :)'
            print('Client Sent: ' + data.lower())
            sock.send(reply.encode())
            break

        elif not data:
            print('Awaiting data...')

        else:
            print('Client Sent: ' + data.lower())
            reply = input(">>>>> :")
            sock.send(reply.encode())

    sock.close()
    return


def main_func():
    TCP_IP = ''
    TCP_PORT = 28990

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    try:
        s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    except Exception:
        print("Binding Error. Already bound." + str(TCP_IP) + str(TCP_PORT))

    s.listen(5)


    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connected to : ' + addr[0] + ' : ' + str(addr[1]))
        _thread.start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
        print(conn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_func()
```

## multi-threaded client.py

```
import socket 

host = 'localhost' 
port = 28990
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096



tcpClientA = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpClientA.connect((host, port))

while True:
    data = tcpClientA.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    print (" Client received data:" + data)
    MESSAGE = input("Client- Enter message :")
    tcpClientA.send(MESSAGE.encode())
```

Responses on Client Side:

```
 Client received data:Yokoso O-genki-desuka:)
Client- Enter message :hello
 Client received data:Server Output: Dono yō ni watashi wa anata o tasukeru kamo shirenai- How may i help you? :D
Client- Enter message :hello
 Client received data:Server Output: Dono yō ni watashi wa anata o tasukeru kamo shirenai- How may i help you? :D
Client- Enter message :hello
 Client received data:Server Output: Dono yō ni watashi wa anata o tasukeru kamo shirenai- How may i help you? :D
Client- Enter message :asdasd



sdfsdf
```

I just can't find anything to solve this problem. Can someone help?

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason for your difficulty. Your code works for me when the indentation is corrected to what I think you meant. Indentation is critical in python, and it's difficult to know what you actually coded because your server-side code is not correct as shown. Copy your code exactly as is out of your editor, paste it into the question box, highlight the code and click the `{}` control. This will place exactly 4 blanks at the beginning of each line.

Comment: One thought: if you simply press Enter, `input` will strip the trailing newline, leaving you with an empty buffer. Sending an empty buffer over a stream socket is a no-op (you cannot send 0 bytes). Hence your server will receive nothing. Perhaps that is the problem? Once you've done that, your client is now stuck waiting in a `recv` but the server is also waiting in a `recv`.

Comment: Also, both sides should be exiting their loop when `recv` returns a null string (that means the other side closed the connection).

Comment: yeah it worked for me too. i think problem was with the sublime text editor i was using. anyways thanks.